# How to check in models save() method if ManyToManyField is empty?

Tags: python, django, many-to-many

I have model with field `rules = models.ManyToManyField(blank=True, null=True)` and `aggregation = models.BooleanField(default=False)`.

And I want to make aggregation=False in case if rules is empty. In other words, if there are no any rule entered or already stored in database, aggregation field should be always == False.

Answer (score 0):

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.rules:
       self.aggregation = False
    super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Is this what you mean?

Edit: I see that you might want to check the database also. No problem:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    models = MyModel.objects.filter(rules__isnull=False).exists()
    if not self.rules and not models:
       self.aggregation = False
    super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: That's what I've done at first time. But it doesn't work: `ValueError at /admin/portal/link/add/
"<Link: http://link.com>" needs to have a value for field "link" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.`

Comment: Your question isn't super well defined. You should have told us you've tried this and added the code for the model if you can.